# trouble with AJAX post of JSON to controller from datatable ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am having trouble getting my ajax call to pass JSON data to my controller.  My application uses ASP.NET 5 with MVC 6 and in this case I am using an datatables JQuery grid.  By the use of checkboxes in my view I am trying to select multiple rows of data and then let the user approve all of the selected rows with one button click.

I am noticing that I am getting the correct selected rows with my javascript, but the data looks like the following when I select two rows before it is passed by AJAX.

```
Selected rows: 2
,1109,tester,3/9/2016,QOL,International Flights,Test email,484.00,Submitted,<a href="/Expenses/Review/1109">Review</a>
   [
      0: "",
      1: "1109",
      2: ""tester",",
      3: "3/9/2016",
      4: "QOL",
      5: "International Flights",
      6: "Test email",
      7: "484.00",
      8: "Submitted",
      9: "<a href="/Expenses/Review/1109">Review</a>",
      length: 10
   ]

,1111,tester,4/13/2016,QOL,Visa Stipend - Visas,total cost test 2,48.00,Submitted,<a href="/Expenses/Review/1111">Review</a>
   [
      0: "",
      1: "1111",
      2: "tester",
      3: "4/13/2016",
      4: "QOL",
      5: "Visa Stipend - Visas",
      6: "total cost test 2",
      7: "48.00",
      8: "Submitted",
      9: "<a href="/Expenses/Review/1111">Review</a>",
      length: 10
   ]
```

I notice my controller action method is being called but it is passing in a null value   Not sure what the issue is as I am using stringify, and put the [FromBody] in the controller.  I am thinking it is perhaps a dataformat issue or my view data not matching my viewmodel.  Here is my code below.

View

```
@model IEnumerable<Expense>

<table class="display nowrap" id="ExpenseTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpenseId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationUserid)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpenseDate)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpenseTypeId)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpenseCodeId)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalCost)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Expense>)ViewData["Expenses"])
        { 
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseId)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FullName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseDate)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseType.ExpenseTypeName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseCode.ExpenseCodeName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCost)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Review" asp-route-id="@item.ExpenseId">Review</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts {
```

Datatables.net jquery script using button to get selected data rows from the grid.  This also uses checkboxes in the first column which the grid submits as null as part of data.  This part appears to be working

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var table = $('#ExpenseTable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    targets: 0
                },
                {
                    targets: [ 1 ],
                    visible: false,
                    searchable: false
                }],
                select: {
                    style: 'multiple',
                    selector: 'td:first-child'
                },

                order: [[1, 'asc']],

                buttons: [
                           {
                               extend: 'selected',
                               text: 'Approve All Selected Expenses',
                               action: function (e, dt, button, config)
                               {
                                   console.log("Selected rows: " + dt.rows({ selected: true }).data().length);
                                   var data = $.map(dt.rows({ selected: true }).data(), function (item)
                                   {
                                       console.log(item)
                                       return item;
                                   });
                                   //console.log(data);
                                   addData(data);
                               }
                           }
                ]            
             } );
        } );

    </script>
```

ajax post method

```
        function addData(data) {
            /*POST*/
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Expenses/ApproveMany',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify( data ),
                cache: false,                
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            })
        }
```

viewmodel

```
public class ApproveVm
        public string check {get;set;}

        public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Requester")]
        public virtual string ApplicationUserid { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}",
            ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Expense Date")]
        public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Expense Type")]
        public int? ExpenseTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Expense Code")]
        public int? ExpenseCodeId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [Display(Name = "Total Cost")]
        public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Review { get; set; }

}
```

controller

```
  [HttpPost]


    public IActionResult ApproveMany([FromBody] IEnumerable<ApproveVm> model)
    {
    }
```

Comment: you forgot the database tables man :)))

Comment: The expense table that is used by the view is just a standard poco class with about 25 fields.  The view above only pulls a subset of those fields.  Also forgot to mention I am using entity framework 7 not that it should make much of a difference.

Comment: Before going further you have to know that when you get table data using .data() method it returns object of selected row's data, So it will contain some metadata not only plain data as you are expecting.  Please modify your data accessing logic accordingly.

Comment: Hi Prakash can you explain how to do modify the data access technology.  is there a different way to access it?